# Pagination with React

Tags: reactjs, pagination

My pagination is doing something strange. I use [react-pager](https://github.com/AZaviruha/pager).

When I click on the first page - I have not any items (but I heed them), when I click on the second page I have 4 items and when I click on the third page my items just added to the items from the second page. I mean on the third page I have 8 items old+new, not 4 new items like I heed.
I think something wrong in slice.

Component is below:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import Pager from 'react-pager';

class AlbumsShow extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.renderImage = this.renderImage.bind(this);
        this.handlePageChanged = this.handlePageChanged.bind(this);

        this.state = {
            total:       3,
            current:     1,
            visiblePage: 2,
        };
    }

    handlePageChanged(newPage) {
        this.setState({ current : newPage });
    }

    renderImage() {
        return this.props.images.slice((this.state.current-1), this.state.current * 4).map(image => (
            <li key={image.id}>
                <img className="album_img" alt="job" src={image.img} />
                <p className="album_title">Test</p>
            </li>
        ));
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div>
                    {this.renderImage()}
                </div>
                     <Pager
                        total={this.state.total}
                        current={this.state.current}
                        visiblePages={this.state.visiblePage}
                        titles={{ first: '<|', last: '>|' }}
                        className="pagination-sm pull-right"
                        onPageChanged={this.handlePageChanged}
                    />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
    const currentAlbumId = parseInt(ownProps.params.id, 10);

    return {
        images: state.main.albums.filter(album => album.id === currentAlbumId)[0].images,
    };
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(AlbumsShow);
```

Also if I will have more 10 items my pagination should be visible and if less than 10 - null, but my condition is not working too. For example:

```
            {this.renderImage() > 10 ?

             <Pager
                total={this.state.total}
                current={this.state.current}
                visiblePages={this.state.visiblePage}
                titles={{ first: '<|', last: '>|' }}
                className="pagination-sm pull-right"
                onPageChanged={this.handlePageChanged} 
            />: null }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess `this.state.current` is the page number. So your slice may be something like this:

`slice(this.state.current * 4, (this.state.current + 1) * 4 - 1)`

**EDIT:**
I didn't see your second question. If you don't want your pagination if more than 10 items you can do:

```
    {this.props.images.length > 10 ?

         <Pager
            total={this.state.total}
            current={this.state.current}
            visiblePages={this.state.visiblePage}
            titles={{ first: '<|', last: '>|' }}
            className="pagination-sm pull-right"
            onPageChanged={this.handlePageChanged} 
        />: null }
```

**EDIT 2:**
Oops, current starts at 0 not 1. I edited the slice above.

**EDIT: 3:**
If you want to display all images when you have less than 10 items you can do something like this:

```
  renderImage() {
    const imgs = this.props.images.length > 10 ?
      this.props.images.slice(this.state.current * 4, (this.state.current + 1) * 4 - 1) :
      this.props.images;
    return imgs.map(image => (
      <li key={image.id}>
        <img className="album_img" alt="job" src={image.img} />
        <p className="album_title">Test</p>
      </li>
    ));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <ul>
        {this.renderImage()}
      </ul>

      {this.props.images.length > 10 ?

        <Pager
          total={this.state.total}
          current={this.state.current}
          visiblePages={this.state.visiblePage}
          titles={{ first: '<|', last: '>|' }}
          className="pagination-sm pull-right"
          onPageChanged={this.handlePageChanged} 
        /> : null
      }
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: It helps and my items don't add to each other, but my first page still empty.

Comment: Pagination works, thank you.
I have one more question about conditions:
When I paste your edits to my code my items disappeared, but console is clear.

Comment: Do you mean when you have less than 10 images you display 0 image? If so this is normal because you return null if the condition is false. I will edit my answer to show you how to do it.

Comment: Look, when I have less than 10 images - I need to do my pagination invisible and all my items should display, but when items more than 10 - I have 10 items on one page and my pagination visibe.

Comment: Check my EDIT 3, this should work. I just re-edited it, just now so be sure to use my last EDIT 3. Refresh this stackoverflow page to display last version.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145100/discussion-between-valeria-shpiner-and-damien-monni).

Answer (score 0):

Another component handling paging is [react-pagination-custom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-pagination-custom).

```
<TinyPagination
    total = {...}
    selectedPageId = {...}
    itemPerPage = {...}
    renderBtnNumber = {...}
    maxBtnNumbers = {...}
    preKey = '...'
    nextKey = '...'
    {...someOptionalProperties}
/>
```

It allow you custom everything (number buttons, wrap container, spread,..). Its document is well, demo is also clear.